# How to resolve the error "unable to access 'github url': getaddrinfo() thread failed to start"?

Tags: git

I wanted to push changes to my repository on Github, I used the command,
git remote add origin url
then tried to push changes using the command git push origin master and I'm getting this error.
Please some one help !

I tried both with http and https urls, both giving the same error.[image: Screenshot of the same]

Answer (score 0):

This error could be because of firewall or network related. Change your network and try to push the changes.
 If any firewall installed in your system try to reinstall it or turn off git access to it.
If you are using windows defender firewall, restart it and try again.

Comment: Hey Monali ! Thanks for the answer, Yeah I tried disabling and again enabling windows defender firewall , i don't know if it resolved the issue or not. I was then trying the same with ssh key instead of url but in the middle I tried with url, somehow it worked !!

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and up-voting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer